# XSLT XPath Correct Syntax for adding an element to a preceding-sibling

Tags: xslt, xpath, syntax-error, addition, siblings

Every time I try to do something similar to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted+preceding-sibling::wd:Result_Lines/wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted"></xsl:value-of>
```

I get an error in Oxygen saying something to the effect of...

```
Description: XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second operand of '+'
```

I have tried turning each situation into a variable and then calling the variables in an add function and tried creating a sequence. Nothing seems to be working:

```
<xsl:variable name="child_support" select="preceding-sibling::wd:Result_Lines/wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted[position()=1]"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted+(concat($child_support, '')))"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:sequence select="format-number(preceding-sibling::wd:Result_Lines/wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted+wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted, '#')"></xsl:sequence>
```

Here is something similar to the xml I am trying to call for the addition operators:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-INT034-ADP-Garnishment_Disbursements_File-Outbound2">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Result_Lines>
      <wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted>2</wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted>
    </wd:Result_Lines>
    <wd:Result_Lines>
      <wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted>276.92</wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted>
    </wd:Result_Lines>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

What am I missing? If I created an xslt function would that work? XSLT functions are not something I've ever created before.

I could use some help figuring out what the problem is.

Thanks,
Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted |
                          preceding-sibling::wd:Result_Lines/
                                 wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted)" />
```

Or a little cleaner:

```
<xsl:variable name="thisAndPreceding"
              select=". | preceding-sibling::wd:Result_Lines" />
<xsl:value-of select="sum($thisAndPreceding/wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted)" />
```

Comment: The first one seemed to work just fine. You are amazing!!! Thanks! I had to adjust it slightly <xsl:value-of select="sum(wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted | preceding-sibling::wd:Result_Lines/wd:XMLNAME_57-Payment_Deducted)"></xsl:value-of>

Comment: Great to hear that and thanks for the correction. Please mark this answer as accepted if your problem is solved. :)